# ¿Como bloqueo un if en un bucle while?

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, while, python-3.7

```
h = 0
 while h < 4:
    ronda= input("-   Ingrese ronda: ")
    if ronda == '1':
       puntos = int(500)

    if ronda == '2':
       puntos = int(125)
            
    elif ronda == '3':
       puntos = int(0)
            
    h += 1
```

> si en una vuelta elijo la ronda '1' como puedo hacer para que despues de esa vuelta no vuelva a entrar mas a ese if (aunque elija otra vez la ronda '1'

Comment: Podrías agregar un flag

Comment: gracias por responder, en donde dices de agregarlo?

Comment: Ya te dieron una respuesta y es parecido a lo que planeaba

Comment: Más allá de las soluciones ofrecidas, quería resaltar que, si estás seguro de que lo escrito siempre será un entero, no es necesario rodear dicho entero con la función int. Escribir un entero SIN COMILLAS en Python ya te crea un entero. Por lo que puedes cambiar lineas como `int(500)` por `500`.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera general y extensible de tratar el problema es definir un diccionario que cuente cuantas veces el usuario ha ingresado cierta opción.

Usaremos un `defaultdict`, que es un diccionario con la habilidad de crear automáticamente una entrada cuando usas una llave nueva. En tal caso, `defaultdict` genera la entrada con valor cero.

El diccionario está inicialmente vacio y se puebla con las `ronda` que el usuario ingrese

```
from collections import defaultdict


h = 0
apariciones = defaultdict(int)
while h < 4:
    ronda = input("-   Ingrese ronda: ")
    if ronda == '1' and apariciones[ronda] == 0:
        puntos = int(500)

    if ronda == '2':
        puntos = int(125)

    elif ronda == '3':
        puntos = int(0)

    apariciones[ronda] += 1
    h += 1

print(apariciones)
```

En cada iteración sumamos 1 al contador de la ronda correspondiente.

Para implementar lo pedido, basta chequear el valor del contador:

```
if ronda == '1' and apariciones[ronda] == 0:
```

Al final de cada iteración, incrementamos el contador correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando el ejemplo de flaguear y tratando de conservar tu lógica qudearía de la siguiente manera:

```
h = 0
puntos = 0
seleccionado_1 = False

while h < 4:
    ronda= input("-   Ingrese ronda: ")
 
    if seleccionado_1 == False:
        if ronda == '1':
           puntos += int(500)
           seleccionado_1 = True
    else:
        if ronda == '2':
           puntos += int(125)
            
        elif ronda == '3':
           puntos += int(0)    
    h += 1
```

Sumé los puntos para tener alguna forma de control.